# How to randomly filter rows to achieve desired proportions of a grouping variable

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, sample

I have data with a group variable, and I want to sample rows to end up with certain proportions in the group variable. This might require filtering rows, as the following example shows.

**Simulating data**

```r
set.seed(2021)

my_df <-
  data.frame(animal = sample(rep(c("dog", "cat", "rabbit"), times = c(150, 4100, 220))),
           weight = sample(5:25, size = 4470, replace = TRUE))

> head(my_df)
##   animal weight
## 1    cat     11
## 2    cat     24
## 3    cat      9
## 4    cat     20
## 5    cat     11
## 6 rabbit      9
```

Here we have data about 4470 animals, which could be either cat, dog, or rabbit, and the weight of each individual animal.

If we summarize the proportions of animals of each type we get:

```r
library(dplyr)

my_df %>%
  group_by(animal) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))

## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##   animal     n   freq
## * <chr>  <int>  <dbl>
## 1 cat     4100 0.917 
## 2 dog      150 0.0336
## 3 rabbit   220 0.0492
```

We thus learned that in `my_df`, 91.7% of the data are cats, 4.92% are rabbits, and 3.36% are dogs.

---

**Desired Output: Sampling rows from the data to end up with other proportions over `animal` column**

I realized that my data in `my_df` is not representative of the population I study, and therefore I want to sample rows to alter the proportions.

I want to end up with data that is comprised of 70% cats, 15% dogs, and 15% rabbits. Obviously, I'll need to throw away many of the `cat` rows to reach such distribution.

Is there a simple way to reach such random sampling, to meet a desired proportion over a grouping variable?

---

EDIT

---

To clarify, in `my_df` reaching the desired proportions between cat:dog:rabbit requires throwing away not only cats, but potentially dogs and rabbits too.

---

EDIT 2

---

In the comments, @Limey suggested [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66476142/sample-from-a-data-frame-using-group-specific-sample-sizes), which is indeed relevant. However, I've tried applying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66476655/6105259) solution from there but it didn't give the expected output.

```r
library(purrr)

group_slice_prop <- c(cat = 0.7, dog = 0.15, rabbit = 0.15)

output <-
  my_df %>% 
  split(.$animal) %>% 
  imap_dfr(~ slice_sample(.x, prop = group_slice_prop[.y]))
```

We get that `output` is:

```r
output %>%
  group_by(animal) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))

## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##   animal     n    freq
## * <chr>  <int>   <dbl>
## 1 cat     2870 0.981  
## 2 dog       22 0.00752
## 3 rabbit    33 0.0113
```

But I was expecting to summarize `output` and get:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  animal     n    freq
* <chr>  <int>   <dbl>
1 cat       ?     0.70  
2 dog       ?     0.15
3 rabbit    ?     0.15
```

---

EDIT 3

---

Both @AnilGoyal and @Chris Ruehlemann proposed solutions that *do* work in this case, but are somewhat limited to the toy data I provided. We could have thought about other scenarios with different, less intuitive proportions, or otherwise more levels in the group variable that require different math to figure out the `n` per group. I want to avoid that. I wish to specify the desired *blend of proportions* in the group variable, and let the code decide how many rows to throw away from each group category to reach that blend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sample from a data frame using group-specific sample sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66476142/sample-from-a-data-frame-using-group-specific-sample-sizes)

Comment: @Limey, it's relevant but doesn't answer my question. I've updated my question to account for my attempt to use a solution from the post your referred to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITed answer in view of EDIT-3**

```
#desired sample sizes
samp <- tibble(animal = c('cat', 'dog', 'rabbit'), 
       prop = c(0.70, 0.15, 0.15)) 

arrange(count(my_df, animal), n) %>% left_join(samp, by = "animal") %>%
  mutate(n1 = first(n)/first(prop),
         n = prop * n1) %>% select(-prop, -n1) %>%
  right_join(my_df, by = "animal") %>%
  group_split(animal) %>%
  map_df(~sample_n(.x, size = first(n))) %>%
  select(-n)
# A tibble: 1,000 x 2
   animal weight
   <chr>   <int>
 1 cat        19
 2 cat         7
 3 cat        17
 4 cat        11
 5 cat        22
 6 cat         8
 7 cat        22
 8 cat        14
 9 cat        22
10 cat        18
# ... with 990 more rows
```

Try this out on different df

```
set.seed(123)
my_df <-
  data.frame(animal = sample(rep(c("dog", "cat", "rabbit"), times = c(1500, 4100, 220))),
             weight = sample(5:25, size = 5820, replace = TRUE))

library(tidyverse)
samp <- tibble(animal = c('cat', 'dog', 'rabbit'), 
       prop = c(0.70, 0.15, 0.15)) 

arrange(count(my_df, animal), n) %>% left_join(samp, by = "animal") %>%
  mutate(n1 = first(n)/first(prop),
         n = prop * n1) %>% select(-prop, -n1) %>%
  right_join(my_df, by = "animal") %>%
  group_split(animal) %>%
  map_df(~sample_n(.x, size = first(n))) %>%
  select(-n) -> sampled

library(janitor)  
tabyl(sampled$animal)

 sampled$animal    n   percent
            cat 1026 0.6998636
            dog  220 0.1500682
         rabbit  220 0.1500682
```

Comment: thanks, @AnilGoyal. Please see my "EDIT 3" above. I've addressed your solution there. Maybe just a small tweak is needed...

Comment: Check it now please.  I think you want a general solution when number of rows for each group (say animal) is just random and not fixed beforehand

Comment: Exactly. I guess I didn't communicate my intention clearly enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a tibble with animal name and target percentage that you need in the final dataframe and sample rows for each animal based on it.

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(animal = c('cat', 'dog', 'rabbit'), 
       prop = c(0.70, 0.15, 0.15), 
       n = nrow(my_df) * prop) %>%
  left_join(my_df, by = 'animal') %>%
  group_by(animal) %>% 
  sample_n(size = first(n), replace = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-prop, -n) -> result
```

Checking the proportion :

```
result %>% count(animal) %>% mutate(n = prop.table(n))

# animal     n
#  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 cat    0.700
#2 dog    0.150
#3 rabbit 0.150
```

Comment: Thanks! But note that if we `count(result, animal)` there are `670` dogs and `670` rabbits, which doesn't make sense. In `my_df` there are `150` dogs and `220` rabbits. So there could not be more dogs/rabbits than in the original data.

Comment: @Emman  So then you want to reduce the number of rows ? `result` would be less than 4470 rows to achieve the desired proportion.

Comment: Reducing is inevitable. I wrote in the question "Obviously, I'll need to throw away many of the cat rows to reach such distribution."

Comment: My answer throws away cat rows. You did not specify anything about dog and rabbit rows.

Comment: @Emman, but what you didn't do was specify the size of your sampled dataset.  That's a critical piece of information.

Comment: I probably don't understand the solution. How could there be more group members (for example, dogs) than in the original data?

Comment: They're chosen with replacement (replace =true).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step-wise solution basd on the fact noted in a comment that " there are 150 dogs and 220 rabbits" and that dogs and rabbits are supposed to account for 15%:

```
cats <- my_df %>%
  filter(animal == "cat") %>%
  sample_n(700)
rabbits <- my_df %>%
  filter(animal == "rabbit") %>%
  sample_n(150)
dogs <- my_df %>%
  filter(animal == "dog")

my_newdf <- rbind(cats, rabbits, dogs)
```

Check:

```
my_newdf %>%
  group_by(animal) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  animal     n  freq
* <chr>  <int> <dbl>
1 cat      700  0.7 
2 dog      150  0.15
3 rabbit   150  0.15
```