# Sample different number of observations by level of a factor in R

Tags: r, random, subset, sample

In my dataset, I have a factor with many levels, and each level has a different number of observations (from 3 to 20). I want to sample randomly a different number of observations by level, let's say 7 for level A, 5 for level B, 8 for level C and so on. Of course, I cannot select more observations than each level has. I want to replicate the process `n` times and save the obtained subsets in separate dataframes.
How can I do that? I have already searched on google without success and I have applied this code, but it only selects the same number of rows from each level (in this case `3`):

`x <- ddply(df, ~Area, function(x){ndf <- x[sample(nrow(x),3), ]})`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of dplyr's `slice_sample()` and purrr.
I'm assuming you want to do the sensible thing and sample a constant proportion of the total.

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice_sample(prop = 0.8)
#> # A tibble: 120 × 5
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3 setosa 
#>  2          4.8         3            1.4         0.1 setosa 
#>  3          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#>  6          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  7          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.3         3            1.1         0.1 setosa 
#> 10          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#> # … with 110 more rows
```

Then, use purrr to get the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)
map_dfr(
  seq_len(3),
  ~ iris %>% 
      group_by(Species) %>% 
      slice_sample(prop = 0.8)
)
#> # A tibble: 360 × 5
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5           3.5          1.3         0.3 setosa 
#>  2          5.8         4            1.2         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#>  4          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4 setosa 
#>  6          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  7          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  8          4.4         3            1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.3         3            1.1         0.1 setosa 
#> 10          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4 setosa 
#> # … with 350 more rows
```

#### Edit 1

If you must specify by size, [@r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans)'s [answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66476142/sample-from-a-data-frame-using-group-specific-sample-sizes) yields the following possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
group_sizes <- tibble(
  Species = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
  size = c(12, 30, 33)
)
map_dfr(
  seq_len(3),
  ~ iris %>% 
      left_join(group_sizes, by = "Species") %>% 
      group_by(Species) %>% 
      mutate(samp = sample(n())) %>% 
      filter(samp <= size) %>% 
      select(-c(size, samp)) %>% 
      ungroup()
)
#> # A tibble: 225 × 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  
#>  1          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  3          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#>  4          4.3         3            1.1         0.1 setosa 
#>  5          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4 setosa 
#>  6          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  7          5           3            1.6         0.2 setosa 
#>  8          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.4         3            1.3         0.2 setosa 
#> 10          5           3.5          1.3         0.3 setosa 
#> # … with 215 more rows
```

If you want random sizes each time you can do the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)
map_dfr(
  seq_len(3),
  ~ iris %>% 
      left_join(
        iris %>% 
          count(Species) %>% 
          rowwise() %>% 
          mutate(size = sample(1:n, 1)),
        by = "Species"
      ) %>% 
      group_by(Species) %>% 
      mutate(samp = sample(n())) %>% 
      filter(samp <= size) %>% 
      select(-c(size, samp, n)) %>% 
      ungroup()
)
#> # A tibble: 246 × 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> 10          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2 setosa 
#> # … with 236 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I do it without selecting a constant proportion of the total?

Comment: Updated answer for specifying size.

Comment: Thank you, the link you posted is what I was looking for.