# sample a predefined number of observations per group

Tags: r, tidyverse, nest, sampling

My data looks like this:

```
> data|>head(20)|>dput()
structure(list(id = c("42190204", "34390202", "34310104", "34310104", 
"34310104", "34310104", "34310104", "34310104", "34310104", "34310104", 
"34310104", "34310104", "34310104", "34310104", "34310104", "34310104", 
"34310104", "34310104", "34310104", "34310104"), sample_size = c(0, 
7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Also, my data has NAs in sample_size which I am filtering out. For some id, i have as many as 800+ observations, so in some cases my sample_size is larger than number of available observations for group id and in some cases my sample_size is smaller than the number of observations. In the first case would be ideal to just repeat the existing observations to make up the sample_size and in the second case - just select observations at random.

from each group (which is id column) i need to randomly select number of observations equal to the sample_size for this group (=id).

I am looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72628560/randomly-select-sample-from-each-group-using-weight) and trying it with `nest()` but it does not work.. the code finishes with no error, but the number of observations under each group does not match the sample_size... How to fix this?

My code:

```
test<-data|>filter(!is.na(sample_size))|>nest(id)|>
  mutate(
    data_sample = map2(data, sample_size, ~ slice_sample(.x, n = .y))
  ) %>%
  unnest(cols = data_sample)
```

Comment: What does "repeat" mean in this context? Sample with replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you don't nest the `id` column (having an example `value` column to sample from here):

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(22)

n_samples <- tibble(
  id = 1:100,
  sample_size = sample(0:20, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

tibble(id = rep(1:100, each = 10), 
       value = runif(1000, 10, 100)) |> 
  left_join(n_samples, by = join_by(id)) |> 
  nest(data = -c(id, sample_size)) |> 
  mutate(data_sample = map2(data,
                            sample_size, 
                            ~ slice_sample(.x, n = .y, replace = TRUE))) |> 
  unnest(data_sample) |> 
  select(-data)
#> # A tibble: 1,097 × 3
#>       id sample_size value
#>    <int>       <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1           5  63.9
#>  2     1           5  28.5
#>  3     1           5  83.4
#>  4     1           5  83.4
#>  5     1           5  98.5
#>  6     2           8  68.2
#>  7     2           8  39.8
#>  8     2           8  68.2
#>  9     2           8  39.8
#> 10     2           8  68.2
#> # ℹ 1,087 more rows
```

This returns a set of `sample_size` rows for each `id`. The `replace = TRUE` allows re-sampling when the required size is bigger than the number of rows in the group.

Comment: thank you! I was soooo close! but was "nesting" over wrong value, shame on me!